# "message": "Unexpected number in JSON at position 1"

Tags: postman, sendinblue

I've a problem with postman.
When i sent my data to sendinblue with API, i got a response => "message": "Unexpected number in JSON at position 1"

My data is here :

```
"updateEnabled":true
"smtpBlacklistSender":["user@example.com"]
"smsBlacklisted":false
"emailBlacklisted":false
"listIds":[27]
"email":"test@pakat.net"
"attributes":{"FNAME":"Elly","LNAME":"Roger"}
```

I will attache my images

**[my data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OpQ4W.jpg)
[api helper](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FHfpw.jpg)**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You chose the wrong content-type for post request. Put it in `Body > raw > json` like this:

[image]

with correct json format:

```
{
    "updateEnabled": true,
    "smtpBlacklistSender": [
        "user@example.com"
    ],
    "smsBlacklisted": false,
    "emailBlacklisted": false,
    "listIds": [
        27
    ],
    "email": "test@pakat.net",
    "attributes": {
        "FNAME": "Elly",
        "LNAME": "Roger"
    }
}
```